# Cassandra Data Modelling

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I'm trying out Cassandra (being using Elasticsearch a lot) and am technically new to this but I would like to know what's the best way to make all my columns searchable.
So far, it's discourage not to use secondary index if you have lot's of unique values in your columns which is true for my case.

```
create table REPORT(    
    Id int PRIMARY KEY, 
    col1 varchar,
    createdAt timestamp,
    col2 varchar,
    col3 varchar,
    ... #Some more columns,
    col400 varchar  
) with clustering order by (createdAt desc);
```

Any thought ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that if you're using DSE, your only choice is to use bundled [Solr](http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchIntro.html) to index all your columns.

There's also a [stargate-core](https://github.com/tuplejump/stargate-core) plugin for cassandra which allows to have Lucene-based indexes stored inside C*.